# Update a Map value document value using Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document like myPortCollection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55efce10f027b1ca77deffaa"),
    "_class" : "myTest",
    "deviceIp" : "10.115.75.77",
    "ports" : {
        "1/1/x1" : {
            "portId" : "1/1/x1",
             healthState":"Green"
```

I tried to update

```
db.myPortCollection.update({
    { deviceIp:"10.115.75.77"},
    { "chassis.ports.1/1/x10.rtId":"1/1/x10" },
    { $set: { "chassis.ports.1/1/x10.healthState" : "Red" }
})
```

But I am getting error that attribute names mentioned is wrong,.Please help in specifying the syntax properly for embedded map document update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "query" portion is wrong as you have split conditions into two documents. It should be this:

```js
db.myPortCollection.update(
    { 
        "deviceIp":"10.115.75.77",
        "chassis.ports.1/1/x10.rtId":"1/1/x10"
    },
    { "$set": { "chassis.ports.1/1/x10.healthState" : "Red" } }
)
```

And as long as the query then matches ( valid data not shown in your question ) then the specified field will be set or added.

Comment: Thanks Blakes,I have tried similarly as well but still some error in the > db.cachedNodeChassis.update({"deviceIp":10.115.75.77","chassis.ports.1/1/x10.p
ortId":"1/1/x10"},{$set:{"chassis.ports.1/1/x10.duplex":"test"}})
2015-09-09T14:28:18.793+0530 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Comment: @NarayanaPachava Please cut and paste from above. Your error suggests you are typing something in and you are not quoting fields correctly. Check that all "dot notated" fields are contained fully within quotes. You also appear to have supurflous braces `{}` in the statement there. Compare to the above again at least.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Blakes Seven it worked !! Appreciate your prompt response

Comment: on the same note I have a question if the field healthState is not already available then modified records collection coming as 0,how we can force to create a column in the same collection and update the healthState attribute for the following **> db.cachedNodeChassis.update({"deviceIp":"10.115.75.77","chassis.ports.1/1/x10.
portId":"1/1/x13"},{ "$set": { "chassis.ports.1/1/x13.healthState" : "Red" } })
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })

Comment: @NarayanaPachava [Ask a new Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). That is how StackOverflow works. It is not a discussion forum or a mailing list, but a repository of "Questions" and "Answers". I know it's tempting to keep asking someone who provided you an answer all your questions, but it is not how this works here. If you have more questions then add them. See your reputation already increased since you accepted an answer. Ask more, accept more, unlock things and most importantly remove advertising.

Comment: Thanks Blakes for the clarififcation,I am new to this forum posted my question.